Dessert at Vowelburgers™
Inspired by Avi's Vowelburger™ Riddle
Vowelburgers™ has just announced a new dessert menu, with 12 different varieties of sandwich cookie. Can you figure out the desserts, and what they have in common?



Filling
Vowelburger™




eɪ
injure


i
estate


aɪ
snug


oʊ
recognized


u
menageries


æ
cheek


ɛ
passed


ɪ
concert


ɑ
duck


ə
calm


aʊ
promote


ɔ
bellow




The vowel burgers

 Are based on the International Phonetic Alphabet.
 

Here are the completed burgers

 The highlighted word is the ‘phonetic spelling’.

 eɪ - meɪm (Maim)
 i  - fif  (Fief)
 aɪ - taɪt (Tight)
 oʊ - noʊn (Known)
 u  - zuz  (Zoos)
 æ  - sæs  (Sass)
 ɛ  - dɛd  (Dead)
 ɪ  - gɪg  (Gig)
 ɑ  - bɑb  (Bob) (American pronunciation)
 ə  - ləl  (Lull)
 aʊ - taʊt (Tout)
 ɔ - rɔr (Roar)

These

 All have the two of the same phonetic consonants as their Buns!


Ha, stuck on the æ and the ə. (But I think your ə doesn't quite fit the menu.)

I think the æ is supposed to be sæs. Surely the ə is something else as well.

Correct...well done! Also, all pronunciations are based on the American pronunciations as documented in the OED.

@JeremyDover haha yeah that threw me off for ‘Duck’. I am British you see with a somewhat London accent. But I remembered you were American and remembered this scene from a movie https://youtu.be/JfFvZLUwsCc?feature=shared
